# php website connect to database server

Tags: php, mysql, database, localhost

I am trying to connect my php website to a database for users to register,log in, and other things.  every time i try to test the log in page with a dummy account i created in the mysql database, when i enter the info, I keep getting the internal 500 error, meaning there is something wrong with my code. i have tried different arrangements of code from different tutorials to see if that's the issue, but nothing works.  I understand there are different styles of coding, such as using " " , as opposed to  ' ' . in the code and i have tested them all, got nothing. please help. below is my code, all in MAMP, htdocs. SD is the folder, and database name.

```
**connect.php** :

    <?php
    $connect_error= 'Sorry, we are experiencing connection problems.';
    $db_name = "SD";
    $connection = @mysql_connect("localhost:8888", "root","root") or die($connect_error);
    $db = @mysql_select_db($db_name,$connection) or die($connect_error);
    ?>

**login.php** : 

        <?php
    include 'SD/init.php';

    if (empty($_POST) == false){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if (empty($username) == true || empty($password) == true){
            $errors[] = 'Please enter a username and password';
        }else if (user_exists($username) == false) {
            $errors[] = 'We cannot find that username.  Have you registered yet?';
        }else{  
            $login = login($username, $password);
            if ($login == false){
                $errors[] = 'That username/password combination is incorrect';
            }else {
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
                header('Location: index.php');
                exit();
            }
        }

        print_r($errors);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Have you checked your apache logs?

Comment: an error (you can find that in your logs) would be helpful.

Comment: Turn on error reporting.  At the top of the file place `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @NathanMann: that's valid php syntax. it's the equivalent of `array_push($arr, 'value')`

Comment: @MarcB My entire life is a lie.

Comment: i checked the apache error log, im getting a lot of "file does not exist" errors with several of my php files. also i opened terminal (MAC OSX) and i was able to sign in with the regular root password

Comment: @John [Fri Mar 01 13:59:43 2013] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/fonts, referer: http://localhost:8888/SD/index.php

& [Sun Feb 17 22:36:28 2013] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Applications, referer: http://localhost:8888/SD/login.php?login=yes
 most common

Answer (score 0):

500 error to me points to permissions issues. I would check to make sure your files are owned my the right user ls -lah. Also I agree to check the apache error logs would be a good idea. tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log

Another thing to check is make sure you can login to mysql with the username and password mysql -u username -p

Comment: i checked the apache error log, im getting a lot of "file does not exist" errors with several of my php files.
also i opened terminal (MAC OSX) and i was able to sign in with the regular root password. how do i get permissions set?

Comment: In my experience I use the chmod command and 644 usually suites me for files.   chmod 644 filename.php and I use 755 for directories. Good luck hope this helps my experience is mostly linux servers. You may want to check reference paths and .htaccess rewrites as well. Also do the file not exist error reference any files related to your login? Like the connect.php ?

Comment: yes this is one of the most common errors i see
[Sun Feb 17 22:36:28 2013] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Applications, referer: http://localhost:8888/SD/login.php?login=yes

Comment: Take the :8888 off your localhost reference for your mysql connection. mysql is port 3306 by default but you should just say localhost and see if that does anything for you.

Comment: no, it only opens with localhost:8888 , i havent changed anything in the MAMP ports, i left it how it was installed. do you think i should change them to port 80? i read online it was supposed to be port 80?

Comment: when i was using the include function, i deleted the SD/init.php and just put include 'init.php' since i moved the file to htdocs and now its connecting to the server, because it recognizes the username exists, but now it just says that the password doesnt match even though it does.

Comment: thank you for your help! with the apache error logs i was able to determine the error was with the init.php file i have that wasn't correctly written, as far as the location goes.  I am now able to successfully log in and if the password/username do not match, it'll display.. step 1 done !